# Unable to run salt.highstate

Tags: ubuntu, saltstack

I'm working on configuring a group of 40 servers to be managed by SaltStack. I'm testing with just one minion at the moment, which I have successfully added to the master. For simplicity, I'm using the latest version of salt and salt-minion from the Ubuntu 14.04.1 package repository on the respective machines.

I have what appears to be a sane configuration and directory structure, however whenever I try running `salt '*' state.highstate`, I get an error that the top file does not match the nodes. If I try manually running a state file with `salt '*' state.sls worker.users`, it errors that no such file exists. Directory structure and files are below.

Any idea why this is not working?

```
root@salt-master:/srv/salt# tree /srv/salt
/srv/salt
├── worker
│   └── users.sls
└── top.sls

1 directory, 4 files

root@master:/srv/salt# salt '*' state.highstate
worker-2:
----------
    State: - no
    Name:      states
    Function:  None
        Result:    False
        Comment:   No Top file or external nodes data matches found
        Changes:

Summary
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1
------------
Total:     1
```

The contents of the relevant files:

```
root@master:/srv/salt# cat top.sls
base:
  '*':
    - worker.users
root@master:/srv/salt# cat worker/users.sls
    worker:
      user.present:
        - fullname: Service Account
        - shell: /bin/bash
        - home: /home/worker

    admin:
      user.present:
        - fullname: Search Admin Account
        - shell: /bin/bash
        - home: /home/admin
```

File root is defined as follows in the master and I've restarted all the machines:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt
```

Comment: What's in top.sls, it seems like you gave two different outputs:

`
base:
  '*':
    - search
`

Comment: My bad. I had changed some of the names for simplicity. I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you run:
(on master)

`salt-run manage.up`
`salt '*' test.ping`

Comment: Yes, and my one node responds in both.

Comment: have you restarted salt-master and tried to run it in debug mode `salt-master -l debug`

Comment: @Mike, yes. I see the minion connect and accept the job, and attempt to download the relevant .sls file using `salt://worker/users.sls`

Comment: Can you try to run from the minion? `salt-call -l debug state.highstate` IIRC.

Comment: Same log as running it in debug mode off the master--the minion connects, I see the attempts to get the top file, and nothing else. Relevant output here: http://pastebin.com/PMnNWYXJ

Comment: @duiu Can you add the output of `salt-call saltutil.sync_states` from minion to the question?

Comment: I reinstalled salt to the lastest stable version from the saltstack ppa for the master, and the bootstrap script on the minion and now it works. I think there might have been a version mismatch in the default Ubuntu repo.

Answer (score 2):

In general, when debugging **state.highstate** you should try:

`salt` (from master)
`salt-call` (from minion)

#### Minion is reachable

- Ensure you don't have some firewall getting in the way, port 4505 and 4506 should be open to master. See also (http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/firewall.html)
- `salt '*' test.ping` -- Make sure minions respond to ping (this ensures the minion service is running)

#### Versions match (recommended)

- Make sure the version of the minion/master packages match. On Ubuntu for example (`dpkg -l salt-minion` on the minion and `dpkg -l salt-master` on the master).

#### Minion is in correct state

- Clear the cache on the minion completely `rm -rm /var/cache/salt/minion/files/base/*`
- Check to make sure the minion has the right grains `salt-call grains.items`

#### Check logs

- `salt-call -l debug state.highstate` -- Check to see if you can catch more information about the error using "debug" mode
- Check `/var/log/salt/minion`.